# Parametric series with Taylor.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So, I'm having some troubles with this parametric series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} (-1)^n e^{n\beta} [\tan(1/n)+(-1)^n\sin(1/n^2)]^\alpha$

That's how I have tried to solve, partially, but I think there are a lot of errors:

1) We can approximate sin and tan with Taylor expansions but the orders are different...

$\tan(1/n)+(-1)^n\sin(1/n^2)$ = $1/n + o(1/n) +(-1)^n + 1/n^2+ o(1/n^2)$.

Now, the $o(1/n)$ is supposed to annihilate the terms of the sine ($(-1)^n + 1/n^2+ o(1/n^2)$) Am I wrong? If not, now we have the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{n\beta} (1/n)^\alpha$

2) Now for some values of the parameters ($\alpha>0$) and ($\beta<0$) the general term fits the hypothesis of Leibniz' criterion for the convergence of alternating series. I can say the series converges for those values.

3) Then, if we study the absolute convergence, we can try to apply the ratio criterion and the limit to calculate is:

$\lim_{n \to alot}  (1/n+1)^\alpha e^{\beta(n+1)} /(1/n)^\alpha e^{\beta n}= \lim_{n \to alot}e(n/n+1)^\alpha=e>1$

Zero infos so we can try the root criterion...

$\lim_{n \to alot}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(1/n)^\alpha} \sqrt[n]{e^{n \beta}}=e^\beta$ which is $<1$ if $\beta<0$

So we better can say the series converges for every $\alpha$ if: $\beta<0$...

---

---

Am I right? I feel like I'm doing things wrong :|

Comment: minor issue: I think it should be $tan(1/n)+(-1)^nsin(1/n^2)=1/n + o(1/n) +(-1)^n /n^2+ o(1/n^2)$

Comment: it  also  converges for $\alpha>0$ and $\beta=0$ for Leibniz

Comment: it does not converges for $\beta>0$

Comment: @gimusi uh? why ?

Comment: For $\beta>0$ $a_n\not\to0$, isn't it?

Comment: For $\beta>0$ I have 0 * infinite form

Comment: Finally we agree with the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution seems almost complete and correct, we can complete saying that:

1) For $\beta< 0$: $\forall\alpha$ the series always converges for Leibnitz

2) For $\beta= 0$: the series converges for Leibnitz $\forall\alpha >0$ and diverges $\forall\alpha \leq0$

3) For $\beta> 0$: the series does not converge (since $|a_n|\not\to0)$